# Can we use indexOf to match part of a string - Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have an array

```
​def birdArr = ["Geeen is Parrot", "Red is cucumber", "whitePigeon"];
```

Now I need to use indexof function to get the position of that string in array. But I cant give the whole string, but a part of it like below -

```
println(birdArr.indexOf("Parrot"));
```

But it prints -1 means string not present , instead of the correct position. How can we use part of a string in indexof method ? Please help

Comment: you cannot apply the `indexOf()` method to an array in Java! Actually not even `def` is valid in Java, not sure why this question has the [tag:java] tag?!!

Comment: @injecteer yes, why? Is this related to Java? "having problems using or understanding the language itself" as *required* by the [tag:java] tag?

Comment: Sorry for adding Java tag. Removed it.

Comment: `def`, List literals and `println` are obviously NOT present in java, so blame the OP for the wrong question is stupid.

Comment: @injecteer not sure what is more stupid.... trying to correct the question tagging (used by many to search) or [accusing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImsoU.png) me of not reading the question (thoroughly) {and based on the first version of your answer, apparently someone else did not read the question thoroughly... } || I am stopping here, please check [comment everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the `indexOf` method to do a contains check. If you want to do that, use `findIndexOf` to get the index of the first record which contains a string:

```
["Geeen is Parrot", "Red is cucumber", "whitePigeon"].findIndexOf {it.contains("Parrot")}
```

Which will return 0 in this case.

Answer (score 3):

`String` supports `indexOf` which will return the start index within that `String` for the given substring.

```
"Green is Parrot".indexOf("Parrot") // returns 9
```

A `List` doesn't support the method `indexOf` but in Groovy we have `findIndexOf` which iterates the list and returns the first index within the List where the given `Closure` returns true:

```
def list = ["Geeen is Parrot", "Red is cucumber", "whitePigeon"]
list.findIndexOf { it.indexOf("Parrot") >= 0 } // returns 0
list.findIndexOf { it.indexOf("cucumber") >= 0 } // returns 1
list.findIndexOf { it.indexOf("Pigeon") >= 0 } // returns 2
```

Now a somewhat advanced idea of the above is you can use the spread operator  (ie *.) to invoke a common method on each element within the `List` which will return a new `List` with the result of each invocation of that common method.

```
def list = ["Geeen is Parrot", "Red is cucumber", "whitePigeon"]
list*.indexOf("Parrot") // returns [ 9, -1, -1 ]
```

In this case the resulting `List` contains the return value of `String.indexOf` for each element in the `List`.  In the first String at index 0 of our `List` the `String` "Parrot" was found at index 9.  But the other `String`s at indexes 1 and 2 didn't have "Parrot" in them so they return -1.  If you wanted to know the indexes of the array it'd be all indexes where the element at that index > -1.

A key distinction here is that the spread operator executes the method after it on each element of the `List`, but `findIndexOf` will stop when one element returns true from the given `Closure`.

So depending on what you want to know.  One option will find all elements that contain "Parrot" or just if any of the elements contain "Parrot".  Those are important distinctions that will affect which method you want to use.

Comment: Using the spread operator with indexOf is so clever, never would have thought of that!

Comment: Thanks @DanielBlack I thought the OP was having trouble understanding which methods went with which data type.  I was trying to separate out the methods that go with List and the methods that go with String.  The spread operator was close to how the OP was thinking, but it was super risky of confusing things again.  I hope he understood it. :-)